# Exposing a c++ function to python using cython

Tags: python, c++, cython

I am trying to expose a c++ function to python using cython as follows:

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

cdef extern from "auction.h":
    cpdef double util(
        int q, 
        int sq, 
        double alpha, 
        double beta, 
        double kappa, 
        int s, 
        int ss, 
        int m, 
        const vector[double]& p, 
        double a0);
```

I am getting the following (not very descriptive) error:

> src\RFQLib.pyx:4:21: Cannot convert 'double (int, int, double, double,
>   double, int, int, int, const vector[double] &, double)' to Python
>   object

What's the problem here?

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: You could try to change the type of `p` from `const vector[double]&` to list, tuple or numpy array, and then convert to `const vector[double]&`  if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first tell Cython about the function (through the `cdef exetern from` mechanism) and then create a Cython function that calls it, and it's this you can use from Python:

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

cdef extern from "auction.h":
    double util(
        int q, 
        int sq, 
        double alpha, 
        double beta, 
        double kappa, 
        int s, 
        int ss, 
        int m, 
        const vector[double]& p, 
        double a0);

def py_util(int q, 
        int sq, 
        double alpha, 
        double beta, 
        double kappa, 
        int s, 
        int ss, 
        int m, 
        p, 
        double a0):
    cdef vector[double] p_vec = p
    return util(q,sq,alpha,beta,kappa,s,ss,m,p_vec,a0)
```

The slight complication is the conversion to a C++ `vector<double>`. Cython can automatically convert lists/tuples containing appropriate types to vectors. The flipside is that this is done every time you call `py_util` and so probably a bit slow. It's also a problem if `util` stores the reference for use later (probably unlikely, but always possible!) since `p_vec` will have ceased to exist by then.

Two other options are to create a Cython class that wraps `vector[double]`. This is clearly a bit more work for you, but avoids a type conversion on every call of `py_util`. Alternatively you might be able to modify `util` so it uses a `double*`, and use numpy arrays or python arrays on the Python side.